# Command to restore files from an unknown file format?

Tags: command-line, dd

I have many directories inside a parent directory and using `dd` i gave the parent directory `.img` extension as following:

```
dd if=/home/xyz/parentdirectory of=/home/xyz/backup_parent.img
```

How do I get back again the parent directory?

I tried `sudo dd if=/home/xyz/backup_parent.img of=/home/xyz/parentdirectory.tar.bz2` 
and `sudo dd if=/home/xyz/backup_parent.img of=/home/xyz/parentdirectory`

which didn't work. Any other workaround?

Comment: `dd` doesn't work on directories though.

Comment: "I zipped using the dd command" does not make any sense. *Zipping* (jn the sense, making a single [compressed] archive from multiple source files) requires an archiver program. Dd is a reblocker, not an archiver.

Comment: @Hennes I thought of securing the whole directory and gave it as .img extension. I do not know what to call it 'zipping' or 'compressing' or 'combining'. I know that dd is not an archiver, I couldn't know which word to use. I edited the question now. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, understood. No idea how to reverse this usage of dd though. -- For future reference: The usual way to do these kinds of backups is with `tar`.  (`tar cf backup.tar /home/xyz/parentdirectory`). And `tar xf backup.tar` to extract it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you've got there but assuming it is a `dd` image, you can mount it:

```
sudo mount -o loop /home/xyz/backup_parent.img /mnt
```

The contents will be accessible from /mnt for you to copy out.